# NPM requires a peer of but all peers are in package.json and node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm

Im facing the problem that npm on install says

```
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@2.0.1 requires a peer of babel-eslint@^7.2.3 but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@2.0.1 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^5.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN semantic-ui-react@0.74.2 requires a peer of react@>=0.14.0 <= 15 but none was installed.
npm WARN semantic-ui-react@0.74.2 requires a peer of react-dom@>=0.14.0 <= 15 but none was installed.
```

What I think is pretty weird is that I have in fact those dependencies in my package.json and also see them inside the node_modules folder.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-box",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.4",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.0.3",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "2.1.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.3.0",
    "cross-spawn": "5.1.0",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "detect-port": "1.2.1",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.8.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.1",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "filesize": "3.5.10",
    "fs-extra": "4.0.2",
    "gzip-size": "4.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.30.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "0.17.4",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "path-exists": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.6",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "react-dev-utils": "^4.1.0",
    "recursive-readdir": "2.2.1",
    "strip-ansi": "4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "truffle-contract": "^3.0.0",
    "truffle-solidity-loader": "0.0.8",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.1",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-countup": "^2.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.74.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

When trying to install those peers manually like this:

```
npm install babel-eslint --save-dev
```

I still get the error:

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY babel-eslint@8.0.1
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@6.0.2
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.0.0
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@16.0.0
```

Maybe I dont understand how NPM works but to my understanding doing the installs manually at least should solve it, right?

If anyone needs more info just comment and I will provide the additional info. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NPM warnings about peerDeps versions mismatch are correct here. These packages are installed, but installed versions is not supported by some other packages you have.

In your case - they're too new, meaning that maintainers of warning packages are not updated yet to these versions. And restricted required peerDeps version in API-compatible range (no breaking/major version leap).

`eslint-config-react-app@2.0.1` requires a peer deps: `babel-eslint@^7.2.3` (i.e. 7.x.x) and `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^5.1.1` (i.e. 5.x.x).

Your versions is `"babel-eslint": "^8.0.1"` and `"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2"`. The first digit - major - is not matched. This is what `^` (caret) mark is about.

Same with `semantic-ui-react` - they does not support `react@16` yet ( I can't wait too!).

Until then you can install packages with exact major version:

```
> npm view babel-eslint@7.* version // list released versions in required range 7.x.x
babel-eslint@7.0.0 '7.0.0'
babel-eslint@7.1.0 '7.1.0'
babel-eslint@7.1.1 '7.1.1'
babel-eslint@7.2.0 '7.2.0'
babel-eslint@7.2.1 '7.2.1'
babel-eslint@7.2.2 '7.2.2'
babel-eslint@7.2.3 '7.2.3'
> npm install --save-dev babel-eslint@7.2.3 // install latest version in required range
```

Same with other packages.

PS: also, in `package.json` you have to delete duplicated records: `babel-eslint` and `dotenv` in `dependencies`, since they are declared in `devDependencies` already.

Comment: I got it sorted out now but your answer makes me understand npm much better! Thanks a lot :)